# laravel synch causes BelongsToMany::sync() must be of the type array, string given

Tags: php, laravel, data-synchronization

I am trying to synch my tags with the posts table. Two models have `belongsToMany` relationships to eachother in the model.

My view is with bootstrap typeahead to autosuggest me tags and get the old values:

```
<input type="text" data-provide="typeahead" value="{{ Input::old('tags', $theTags) }} class="typeahead" data-items="1" name="tags" "/>
```

iin the controller, I check if a tag is included in the db, otherwise I create db entry for the tag:

```
public function postEdit($postId = null)
    {
        $theTags=array();
        $tags = explode(',', Input::get('tags'));

         //check if tag exists in db        
        foreach ($tags as $key=>$value){
        $dbtag = Tag::where('name', '=', $value)->first();
        array_push($theTags, $dbtag);

        //add to db
        if(!$dbtag){
           $dbtag = new Tag;
           // Update the tag
          $dbtag->name= e(ucwords($value));
          $dbtag->slug  = e(Str::slug($value));
          $dbtag->save(); 
          array_push($theTags, $dbtag);      
           }
         }
        // Update the blog post data
        $post->title  = e(Input::get('title'));

        $author = Author::find(Input::get('author_id'));
        // Was the blog post created?
        if($author->posts()->save($post))
        {
            $post->categories()->sync(Input::get('categories'));
            $post->tags()->sync(Input::get('tags'));

            // Redirect to the new blog post page
            return Redirect::to("admin/blogs/$postId/edit")->with('success', Lang::get('admin/blogs/message.update.success'));
        }

    }
```

I am getting error of :

```
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::sync() must be of the type array, string given, called in /home/ytsejam/public_html/remaker/app/controllers/admin/BlogsController.php on line 273 and defined
```

Can you show me to get the correctly synch the tags ?

ps: I tried to add another array $theTags ,I am using array_push on them .  when I try with

```
$post->tags()->sync($theTags);
```

I am getting illegal offset error:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::sync() must be of the type array, string given`

That error is because you are calling `sync()` with a string, and it should be an array:

```
// Input::get('tags') is a string, this will throw an error
$post->tags()->sync(Input::get('tags'));
```

Now, the other error.

> ps: I tried to add another array $theTags ,I am using array_push on
>   them . when I try with `$post->tags()->sync($theTags);`  I am getting illegal offset error.

I think this error is happening because you are adding `null` values to the `$theTags` array, since you are calling `array_push()` twice.

```
//check if tag exists in db        
foreach ($tags as $key=>$value) {
    $dbtag = Tag::where('name', '=', $value)->first();
    array_push($theTags, $dbtag); // if $dbtag is null, it's being added too
...
```

I would try with this:

```
$theTags=array();
$tags = explode(',', Input::get('tags'));

//check if tag exists in db        
foreach ($tags as $key => $value) {
    $dbtag = Tag::where('name', '=', $value)->first();

    //add to db
    if ( ! $dbtag) {
        $dbtag = new Tag;
        // Update the tag
        $dbtag->name= e(ucwords($value));
        $dbtag->slug  = e(Str::slug($value));
        $dbtag->save(); 
    }

    // Now that you have checked if it's null and created it
    // you can add it safely to the array
    array_push($theTags, $dbtag);      
}
```

and then, try to call `sync()` with the array again: `$post->tags()->sync($theTags);`

Comment: later after midnight, I came to the same solution .but I needed to do array_push($theTags, $dbtag->id); otherwise the db was populated by the names not the ids of the tags. Thank you.